# Place image on border

Tags: css

I am trying to have my image appear on top of a 300px border, as if the border is a background color for the image. This is my code:

```
.containerpagecontent { border-left: 300px solid #fff; } img { float:left; }
```

But it is still not working. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I cannot simply use `background-color` for the image, because the end of the image has to extend off the color.

Comment: We'd need to see the HTML & CSS and the image to help much further but that sounds like a shipload of margin to be adding!

Comment: After you changed the question code (from `margin` to `border`), it should work as-is. Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as:

```
margin-left: 300px solid #fff;
```

you probably meant:

```
border-left: 300px solid #fff;
```

Also, see if something like this might work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6Rz/. It's using the padding and background properties on a single element to create a border.